# Django: Default ordering based on a many-to-many related field values and counts

Tags: python, django, django-models

Models look like the following:

```
class Weekday(models.Model):
    '''
    >>> for w in Weekday.objects.all():
    ...  print w
    ...
    Sunday
    Monday
    Tuesday
    Wednesday
    Thursday
    Friday
    Saturday
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name 

class Stop(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ????

    name = models.CharField('Stop name', max_length=32)
    days_open = models.ManyToManyField(Weekday)
```

The kind of ordering I want is:

1. Everything that has all 7 days
2. Everything that has Sunday
3. Everything that has Monday
4. Etc, etc. (with tie breaker being count of weekdays and then stop's name)

Anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this? Should this be done in the manager somehow? Or perhaps there's a simple way to do this?

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify model fields in [Meta.ordering](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/options/#ordering), so if you want to implement that logic you described, you have to resort to [custom manager](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/custom_managers/).

EDIT:

You could add some kind of `weight` field to your `Stop` model, update that field along with updating `days_open` and then you would be able to use *ordering = ['-weight']*

Alternatively, something like this might fit your purposes:

```
Stop.objects.annotate(weight=models.Sum('weekday__weight')).order_by('-weight')
```

-- of course this would require adding `weight` field to `Weekday` model and pre-filling it for all records. This could also be implemented as a method in custom manager I mentioned above.

Comment: Led me down the path! Thanks Mr. Zielinski.